# i am confused about a gerund verb (having)

Tags: sentence-meaning, gerunds

This example comes from my physics book:

> 1) Ripple tank consists of rectangular tray having glass bottom and is pleased nearly half meter above the surface of the table.

I'm not completely sure of the role the verb "having" is playing in this sentence. Is it being used as the complement of the sentence, the object of the sentence or the subject of the sentence? Why couldn't we instead use "have" instead of "having"?

Comment: Please check to make sure that the sentence is the same as the original in your textbook (particularly, the spelling and articles). It's also recommended to cite the source of your text properly in your questions on ELL.

Answer (score 8):

This is not as it stands an idiomatic sentence. What is probably intended is

> The ripple tank consists of a rectangular tray having a glass bottom and is placed nearly half a meter above the surface of the table.

In that sentence *having* is a present participle; the clause which it heads, *having a glass bottom*, acts as an adjectival modifying *a rectangular tray*.

That's perfectly grammatical. We do use the verb *have* to attribute a component or property to a subject:

> The rectangular tray has a glass bottom.

and it is proper to convert that *has* to the participle *having* to turn the predicate into an adjectival. However, few people would actually write or say this. The usual construction for attributing a component or property is a preposition phrase headed by *with*:

> ... a rectangular tray **with** a glass bottom ...

Note, too, that the construction *consists of X* is needlessly wordy. *Consist of* is useful for declaring that a particular subject has multiple parts, but in this case, where only one 'part' is named—the glass bottom is not a distinct part but a component of the tray—it is more graceful to use bare *BE*

> The ripple tank **is** a rectangular tray with a glass bottom and is placed nearly half a meter above the surface of the table.

In fact, the sentence can be further simplified by transforming the first clause into an appositive and eliminating the conjunction:

> The ripple tank, a rectangular tray with a glass bottom, is placed nearly half a meter above the surface of the table.